# Importing data into a scatter plot

Tags: python, scatter

I have a code that generates every possible outcome two types of cards, each reveal showing 6-10 cards. Here is the code:

```
from sequence import deckOrder

for i in range(len(deckOrder)):
   for j in range(len(deckOrder)):

#Draw

first_draw = deckOrder[i]
second_draw = deckOrder[j]

#Before first draw

initial_estimate = 0.5
initial_variance = 1/12

#After first draw 

r_count = first_draw.count('R')
b_count = first_draw.count('B')


alpha = 1 + r_count
beta = 1 + b_count


e_of_theta = alpha/(alpha+beta)

surprise = ((e_of_theta - initial_estimate)**2)/(initial_variance)

var_theta = (alpha * beta)/ ((alpha + beta) **2 *(alpha + beta + 1))

#After second draw 

r_count = second_draw.count('R')
b_count = second_draw.count('B')

new_alpha = alpha + r_count 
new_beta = beta + b_count 

new_e_of_theta = new_alpha/(new_alpha + new_beta)

surprise = ((new_e_of_theta - e_of_theta)**2)/var_theta

#Result
new_list = [surprise]
```

I put the data into a list, but I don't know how to put the outcomes generated by this code into a scatter plot. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Have you looked into matplotlib at all? I think that would help.

Comment: Please do 4-space indentations of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put simple numbers into a scatter plot, define x and y coordinates:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([50,51,52])

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this method. However, the list is within a loop, and every time I try to use it outside that loop I only get one outcome instead of all the possible outcomes. My piece of code works, but I cannot get the data from the loop into the scatter plot. What would you recommend in this case?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. I would use a function which calculates the list contents and returns the list, afterwards you can use the output with the scatter function. Just append all your values using the .append() function in your method, and define the list in the beginning of the method.

Comment: Thank you so so much! What would that look like exactly? Sorry for the inconvenience, but I'm still a beginner and I would really appreciate it.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fjMC6WbT - just a small example - hope I was able to enlighten you.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. I changed it a bit, because the list comprehension for the returned value was not necessary. You can just use a returned list directly if you declare a variable, e.g. new_list = calculateValues(). If you don't know list comprehensions yet, I highly recommend to look into them, as they are really handy and good looking.

Comment: Would this look different if I wanted to create a histogram instead?

Comment: Yes, I would love to upvote but unfortunately I need at least 15 reputation to do that and I don't have that yet. Plus I am new to this platform, so I'm not entirely familiar with how it works yet. However, I am extremely grateful for all the help I received from @jpaodev and have thanked him multiple times for it. Don't be so quick to judge others :) Thank you for your help as well, greatly appreciated!